# Ubuntu 14.04 Phone emulator lock screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-emulator

I am unable to unlock the phone emulator from the Hello page with the pass phrase I entered when starting a newly downloaded emulator. This has happened three times today.

Previous emulators have worked when I typed in, 'phablet' as the pass phrase. 
What do I need to do to get the emulator to start up as if it had just been downloaded ?

Answer (score 1):

It transpires that the unlock code is,

'0000', zero,zero,zero,zero

as is shown when creating an emulator using the terminal as shown in this article from David Planella,

http://www.slideshare.net/DavidPlanella/ubuntu-html5-apps-deep-dive?next_slideshow=1.