# Ubuntu emulator passphrase

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, ubuntu-emulator

I started Ubuntu emulator from Ubuntu SDK for the first time and it's asking me about passphrase. What am I supposed to enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ubuntu 14.04 Phone emulator lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530786/ubuntu-14-04-phone-emulator-lock-screen)

I'm guessing it is like the question above and might be phablet or 0000 (zero, zero, zero, zero).